# CKEDITOR - how to disable multiselect

Tags: ckeditor, multi-select

I would like to know how to disable (switch off) multiselect (multiple part of text selection possibility). Is there some property in configuration?

Thanks, P.

Comment: I think you have to change `getClick : function()` of `CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'listblock'` which you can find in **`plugins\listblock\plugin.js`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the possibility to select multiple regions in Firefox (only it supports this feature) by CTRL-clicking or selecting table columns, then I can't think of a feasible solution. It's not a CKEditor feature, but native browser's feature and to block it you would have to hack selection system.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly this issue. And do you mean it is possible to manage it in the getClick : function () as Sac supposes? The other solution is to ignore the multiselections and applying the functions only on the single-selections in my app.

Comment: I think that Sac meant a possibility to select multiple positions of drop down lists. Listblock plugin is used in e.g. style drop down. Regarding ignoring other ranges - yep, CKEditor does this already - e.g. in editable#insertHtml. Maybe it shouldn't, but to be honest I've never found this important to clarify the way how it handles multiple selections.